# Why elastic search is not indexing the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :doctors_doctor_branches, foreign_key: "doctor_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :doctor_branches, through: :doctors_doctor_branches

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json(
      include: {
        doctor_branches: {only: [:id, :name]}
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Relationship between Doctor and DoctorBranch is correct, as

```
Doctor.find(1).doctor_branches
```

gives me AR array. But when I do

```
response = Doctor.__elasticsearch__.search 'Yoga'
```

I am not getting results for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the indexes? In order to do so you need to run a code like the following:

```
client     = Doctor.gateway.client
index_name = Doctor.index_name
settings = Doctor.settings.to_hash
mappings = Doctor.mappings.to_hash
client.indices.create index: index_name,
                      body: {
                        settings: settings.to_hash,
                        mappings: mappings.to_hash }
```